# Do NDF files move with Alter Database automatically

Tags: sql-server

I know you don't want to hear this but i am not a DBA, but I am responsible for a 2016 SQL server.  From time to time I need to do some DBA work.

This time I need to move the tempdb (mdf, ndf, and ldf files) to another volume.

When i run the alter database query do i need to specify the ndf files in the query?  Or do those move automatically because they are part of the file group?

Being each of the ndfs have logical names, I am thinking I need to, but just want to be certain.

I know I need to specify the LDF files.

These are all the files we have associated with the TEMPDB:

> tempdev   C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL
>   Server\MSSQL13.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\tempdb.mdf
>
> templog   C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL
>   Server\MSSQL13.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\templog.ldf
>
> temp2 C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL
>   Server\MSSQL13.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\tempdb_mssql_2.ndf
>
> temp3 C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL
>   Server\MSSQL13.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\tempdb_mssql_3.ndf
>
> temp4 C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL
>   Server\MSSQL13.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\tempdb_mssql_4.ndf
>
> temp5 C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL
>   Server\MSSQL13.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\tempdb_mssql_5.ndf
>
> temp6 C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL
>   Server\MSSQL13.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\tempdb_mssql_6.ndf
>
> temp7 C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL
>   Server\MSSQL13.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\tempdb_mssql_7.ndf
>
> temp8 C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL
>   Server\MSSQL13.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\tempdb_mssql_8.ndf

Thanks for the help!

-Evan

Comment: Microsoft books online explains how to move tempdb database [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/databases/move-system-databases?view=sql-server-2017#a-moving-the-tempdb-database)

Answer (score 1):

`ALTER DATABASE` can be used to do many things. In order to *move* the file you'll want to use `MODIFY FILE` to move your files to the specified location. This goes for mdf, ndf, ldf. [Erik Darling](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/32281/erik-darling) blogged [about this](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2016/03/moving-databases-with-alter-database/) a while back and gave some examples.

```
ALTER DATABASE [Sample] MODIFY FILE ( NAME = Sample, FILENAME = 'C:\Whatever\Sample.mdf' );
```

From [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/alter-database-transact-sql-file-and-filegroup-options?view=sql-server-2017):

> MODIFY FILE Specifies the file that should be modified. Only one
>    property can be changed at a time. NAME must always be
>   specified in the  to identify the file to be modified. If
>   SIZE is specified, the new size must be larger than the current file
>   size.
>
> To move a data file or log file to a new location, specify the current
>   logical file name in the NAME clause and specify the new path and
>   operating system file name in the FILENAME clause. For example:
>
> To move a data file or log file to a new location, specify the current
>   logical file name in the NAME clause and specify the new path and
>   operating system file name in the FILENAME clause. For example:

Comment: Thanks for your replies!  I was able to move the tempdbs .  Did have a typo in my locations for the ndf files, so i had to remove the files, and then manually add new ones.